# Adding console app project to a solution with .Net Core web api

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, console-application

I added reference to the web api project. The added the following to Program.cs

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        BuildConfig(builder);

        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(
                    options => options.UseOracle(connectionString)); // dbcontext from web api project
                services.AddTransient<IEmailReminderService, EmailReminderService>();
            }).Build();

        var svc = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<EmailReminderService>();

        var er = new EmailReminderService();
        er.OpenIncidentReminder();
    }
    static void BuildConfig(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        _configuration = builder.Build();
    }
}
```

I get System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

_context was null.

*Edit*

```
public class EmailReminderService : IEmailReminderService
    {
        private ModelContext _context;
        //private readonly IExceptionLogService _exceptionLogService;

        public EmailReminderService(ModelContext con)
        {
            _context = con;
            //_exceptionLogService = exceptionLogService;
        }

        public void OpenIncidentReminder()
        {
            var openIncidents = _context.Incidents.ToList();

        }
}
```

Comment: Have you successfully used the DbContext in your web api? Also have you added it to the Contrusctor of the Controller or class you are using it in ?

Comment: Yes. That application is fully functioning. It's a React app actually. I'm trying to create a console app to run queries and send emails daily and weekly.

Comment: .net core can't load the DbContext. You need to change your code for services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(); You probably need to add more info to it. Like which database provider to use, probably the connection string as well if you haven't hard coded it. If your web api also uses .net-core try using the same AddDbContext used in that Startup.cs file.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue. services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(
                        options => options.UseOracle(connectionString)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@terodaktil is right about the configuration of the DbContext. You need to configure it properly to specify the provider. See [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core) about this topic.

```cs
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            // here i'm using in-memory DB, you'd use SqlServer, Oracle, etc.
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(o => o.UseInMemoryDatabase("db"));
            services.AddTransient<IEmailReminderService, EmailReminderService>();
        }).Build();
```

That said, you need to create a scope to resolve a scoped service like `DbContext`.
Then you can use the scope's service provider directly to resolve `IEmailReminderService`, or `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` to create an instance of the concrete implementation `EmailReminderService`.

```cs
using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();

// now you can resolve the dbcontext
var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

// or any service that depends on a scoped service
var reminder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEmailReminderService>();
// var reminder = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<EmailReminderService>(scope.ServiceProvider);

reminder.OpenIncidentReminder();
```

### References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-services-from-main

Comment: I tried to make it similar to what's in the Startup file in the web api project. Still no luck. services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(
                        options => options.UseOracle(connectionString)                      using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<EmailReminderService>();    I get : 'No service for type 'EmailReminders.EmailReminderService' has been registered.'

Comment: Oh, sorry you've registered the service as `IEmailReminderService`, so you need to resolve it like that too: `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEmailReminderService>()`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I get the older previous error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

_context was null.
I've added the EmailReminderSerivce class. Am I missing anything there?

Comment: Can you resolve `ModelContext` from `scope.ServiceProvider`?

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning C# and .Net. service returns context is null

Comment: I've implemented your code as is, and it works fine on my end. See my updated answer

Comment: You can't just new up services `var er = new EmailReminderService();`. You need to resolve them from the DI container.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I need to read more about DI.